# alternative to target="_blank"

Tags: html

What is the best alternative to `target="_blank"`?

Here is the doctype and html declaration we use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Comment: What's wrong with target="_blank"?

Comment: Here's an alternative: Don't open links in new windows.

Comment: @Jan: it's invalid as per XHTML strict (however, I see now, OP is actually using XHTML transitional).

Comment: @RoToRa the link is to a new site (subsidiary of our company)...whats the big deal with a new window?

Comment: @tony: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-usability/new-browser-windows.shtml

Comment: I really wish the target property was better supported... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JS to make the page open in a new window.

```
<a href="test.html" onclick="return ! window.open(this.href);">New Window Open</a>
```

Comment: You will earn headache by selecting this as solution

Comment: @Kumar why are onclicks considered evil?

Comment: Because there you mix content with function. Say your customer wants all external links to open in a new window, then he/she changes her mind. Inline = go through all documents and edit ; external = comment a line of code. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler

Answer (score 3):

It's just valid as per XHTML Transitional. You can keep using them. It's only invalid as per XHTML Strict.

Regardless, for the case that, you could workaround this with a little help of JavaScript. Replace all `target="_blank"` by `rel="ext"` (which is the defacto standard for external links) and run the following (jQuery) script on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel=ext]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: @RoToRa: For a barking (but not biting) w3 validator when using target attribute on XHTML Strict.

Comment: @RoToRa: that's correct. I already found it out and updated the answer at the moment you posted the first comment :) See also the comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the Answer given by BalusC but without the need to modify the html:

http://jsfiddle.net/vC39V/4/

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var LinkTest = {};
        // External Links
        LinkTest.externalLinks = function () {
            $('a[href^=http]').click(function () {
                window.open(this.href);
                return false;
            });
        }();

    });
})(jQuery);
```