# Event handler for a html5 color input element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

Using the new input="color" element within Chrome triggers a new popup dialog:

[image: screenshot color dialog]

I would like to know if there is an event handler that fires as soon as the value in this preview window changes and not only after clicking on "OK"

```
jQuery('#colorinput').on('change', function() { // fires only after clicking OK
    jQuery('#main').css('background-color', jQuery(this).val()); 
 });​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Riesling/PEGS4/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`input` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#common-input-element-events).

Your [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PEGS4/2/) should now work in all (decent) browsers:

```
$('#colorinput').on('input', function() { ... } )
```

Comment: Sadly, Google Chrome seems to no longer support this event as of the date of this comment.

Comment: @acicali: I believe you are mistaken. My fiddle still works on latest release too

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the fiddle. The input event seems to simply mirror the change event in this case, I was expecting different behavior.

Comment: Chrome fires a `change` event when it shouldn't. The difference will be noticeable in Firefox, which treats the events correctly. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1062403

Comment: @jave.web the fiddle I provided works for me on Chrome 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit)

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune it works AFTER clicking on OK .... not while selecting color WHILE colorpicker is opened :)

Comment: Which OS? You should report a bug. On OS X it works fine.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune I would think Windows. I have the latest version of Chrome and the input event doesn't fire until I click ok. Exact OS: Windows 10.

Comment: it works, thank you !! ... just in case you want to use it with vanilla Javascript you may try something like `document.querySelector('#colorinput').addEventListener('input', (e) => ...)` ... it works like a charm !! ;) :)

Answer (score 1):

You really want input event per HTML spec.
Nothing guarantees change event to fire before the input element has lost focus.

"The input event fires whenever the user has modified the data of the control. The change event fires when the value is committed, if that makes sense for the control, or else when the control loses focus. "

Answer (score -2):

To get the value of color input, you should use the event attribute `onchange`provided in [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

```
<input name="eventColor" type="color" onchange="getColorVal(eventColor.value)"/>
```

and define a function that handle the event

```
 function getColorVal(colorValue){

     alert(colorValue);
}
```

Comment: How about instead doing a $('#idname').change(); event?

Comment: This didn't answer the question in this post, onchange is triggering only after ok button click

Comment: Inline Javascript should be avoided (see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/379160)).