# How do we close the default html5 color picker

Tags: html, color-picker

How do we close the default html5 color picker after color selection?

It has to be closed manually everytime its opened.

```
<input type="color">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13805611

Comment: Doesnt it close by default when you selector the color? Atleast it does it in Windows.

Comment: No it doesnt, I am using Mac.

Comment: Same issue here with Mac / Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this, and the correct behaviour only occurs when using the Opera™ Browser. On the Chrome browser only a textbox appeared :(