# Javascript object is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I get the following error and I can't find why:

> TypeError: object is not a function

Here is my html:

```
<td><input type="text" value="" id="cash_retained" name="cash_retained" onkeyup="net_cash()" size="25"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" id="cash_change" name="cash_change" onkeyup="net_cash()" size="25"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="0" id="net_cash" name="net_cash"></td>
```

Here is my js function:

```
function net_cash() {
    var cash = 0;
    var retained = document.getElementById("cash_retained");
    var change = document.getElementById("cash_change");

    cash += parseInt(retained.value);
    cash += parseInt(change.value);

    if (isNaN(cash)) {
        document.getElementById("net_cash").value = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("net_cash").value = cash;
    }
}
```

I can't see for the life of me why this is not working. I have other similar js functions that are finding it just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the problem here is that you have a form element with the same name as your function:

```
<td><input type="text" value="0" id="net_cash" name="net_cash"></td>
```

So when you call `net_cash()` in your `onkeyup` event, it thinks you are referring to this `input` DOM object rather than the function of the same name.  I suggest coming up with separate names for these two things.

Inline event handlers have the enclosing `<form>` element as their executing scope. Each form control with a `name` attribute is treated as though it's a variable in that scope and that's where the conflict comes from.

This is also yet another great reason to use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead of inline event handlers. If you do that, you don't have to worry about your function names conflicting with your element names. See [onclick=“” vs event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196) for more information on the pitfalls of using inline event handlers.

Comment: @eicto: The `window` object is *ridiculously* crowded. That's why I avoid creating *any* globals in my code if I can help it; the markup creates enough of them as it is.

Comment: I'd expected the function declaration to shadow this element-name-as-global-variable quirks?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder same here, but still wow :) where that documented ?

Comment: @eicto: There was a [`window` object spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/) being worked on for a while, but it was abandoned in favor of [this section of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#window). This part of it is in [§5.2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object).

Comment: @eicto A bit of a clarification (20 months late): the name isn't added to `window.var`. What's happening here is that inline event handlers are executed in a certain scope where all of the containing `form`'s named elements exist as variables. The `net_cash()` function is in the global scope, so that's why the `net_cash` element supercedes (hides) it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine for me. See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/EYCYN/)

So make sure of the following

1. Make sure that you are including the script before calling the
   function.
2. Also, it is not a good idea to keep the ids/names and function names same

   ```
   <td><input type="text" value="0" id="net_cash" name="net_cash"></td>
   ```

   // Change the idand name here

Comment: Your demo works, and this would have been my answer too. But at the same time, @JLRishe is right too. The JavaScript DOM is really an enigma...

Comment: Yea.. +1 for JLRishe... I just mentioned that they are repeating.. I didn't think this will create an issue, since I never faced it. :) Thanks...