# Javascript “Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function”

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code is as follows:

```
function change_course(ref) 
{ 
      var arr = ref.split(/\^/);
  document.getElementById('course').value  = arr[0];
  document.getElementById('course_date').value  = arr[1]; 
}
```

This will throw an "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function".

```
<select name="change_course" class="form-control" onChange="change_course(this.value);">';
```

Where is wrong

Comment: From which line is the exception been thrown?

Comment: Maybe there are no elements with the ***`id`s*** `course` and `course_date`?

Comment: @Bergi - No i creat tow element like :- 
`<input type="hidden" name="course" id="course"> <input type="hidden" name="course_date" id="course_date">`

Comment: Why there is a single quote after 'select' tag? Is it inside a variable? Can you show example of options for the select (<option><option/>)

Comment: One of the many pitfalls of using inline event handlers. See [onclick=“” vs event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196) for an explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript object is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423328/javascript-object-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline `onchange` is executed within the same scope as the `form` element (or inner), and `change_course` refers to the `select` element, not to the global function.

To fix this, just give a new value to `select`'s `name` attribute, or rename the function.

Comment: While the `<select>` element is in the scope of the event handler, this particular issue likely exists because the containing `<form>` element is in the scope. A form element has a property for each input, select, etc it contains (which also feels like an a very unexpected behavior).

Comment: @FelixKling Looks like you're right, the wrapping form element is the one, where `change_course` is found. If the [form is stripped](http://jsfiddle.net/kehnckzq/), the error doesn't occur.