# Simple JS Form; Cannot Find Submission Value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm new the JS and I'm having trouble storing and find the value of a form submission. I'm able to create a simple form (as shown below) but I'm not able to find the value of the submission to store for use later.

I thought I was able to access the for value here `var number = document.getElementById('fib-form-number');` but I seem to have done something wrong.

I looked at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157411/how-would-i-store-the-number-in-an-html-form-input-as-a-javascript-variable-when) but that has not seemed to work.

I know the fix is going to be easy .. but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks,

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Form/title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- <input id="input" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return submitted();"> -->
        <!-- Use form to capture numbers on submission -->
        <form id="fib-form">
            <input type="number" id="fib-form-number" min="1">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
// Get value of submission

$(document).ready(function() {

    var form = document.getElementById('fib-form');
    var number = document.getElementById('fib-form-number');

    // Now get the value of the submission
    form.onsubmit = function () {
        var variable = number.value;
        console.log(variable)
    }

});
```

Comment: Hum I've changed it so the spelling is correct but console.log is still not showing the submission.

Comment: When you submit the form the page will reload.

Comment: FYI, you are not preventing the from submission, so as soon as that happens your page is going to reload clearing your log (unless you have preserve log turned on)

Comment: That is probably the reason @PatrickEvans. I think I should not be using a form if my log is going to get cleared

Answer (score 0):

You're misspelling variable:

```
    var variable = number.value;
    console.log(varaible)
```

But you could also use jQuery since you're already using it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('fib-form');
    var number = $('fib-form-number');

    // Now get the value of the submission
    form.onsubmit = function () {
        var variable = number.val();
        console.log(variable)
    }

});
```

Comment: `.val()` is a jQuery method, they are grabbing a DOM object not a jQuery object. Also problems that are the result of misspellings should be closed (eg Typo close reason) not answered