# how to send data to a function using onclick="function myfunction()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my `<ima>` which contains the `data`, `data-commentId`, and I try to use a function to get the data, but it's not working

**JS**

```
function getsome(){
    var comment_id=$(this).attr('data-commentId');
    alert(comment_id);
}
```

**HTML**

```
echo '<img onclick="getsome()" class="c_like_icon" data-commentId="'.$reply_id.'"  src="img/thumb_icon.png"  height="18" width="18">';
```

Comment: `$(this).data('commentId');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `this` inside the function to refer to the element, you have to use `.call` and pass `this` from the inline event handler:

```
onclick="getsome.call(this)"
```

Of course, since you are using jQuery, [there are far better ways to bind event handlers](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/), and I just [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196) why using inline event handlers should be avoided.