# javascript onsubmit not working

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I am trying to make a javascript function work on submitting the form, the function doesnt seem to run. Can anyone help?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function upload(){
                alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return upload();">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Datei hochladen">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When attaching the event handler to the form element, the scope of the event handler is the form and not the window

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return upload(this);">

<script>
    function upload(scope) {
        console.log(scope); // The passed scope from the event handler is
    }                       // the form, and not window
</script>
```

As input elements inside a form are attached as properties to the form object, where the name is the key, calling `upload()` in the event handler, where the scope is the form, would equal calling `form.upload()`, but the form already has an element with that name so `form.upload` is the upload button, not the `upload()` function in the global scope.

To solve it, either rename the function or the element

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function upload(){
                alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return upload();">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload2" value="Datei hochladen">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ybrCC/)

Comment: Actually the problem is not with the a global variable. Usually only for elements with IDs a global variable is created. In this case I believe the properties of the form element are also in the scope of the event handler, so `upload` refers to `form.upload`.

Comment: @FelixKling - You're right, `window.upload` is still the function, it's `form.upload` that causes the issue, or in that scope just `upload`. If I do `onsubmit="window.upload()"` it works. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: the only thing that actually worked for me was using javascript declaration. no idea why, but looks like there's more to this.

Answer (score 1):

My problem, I had without knowing a form inside a form I was interacting with the inner one no matter what I do the outer form always executes

Answer (score -4):

Add return statement in your code

```
<script>
function upload(){
    alert("I am an alert box!");
    return false;
}
</script>
```