# Why won't the onChange event, of the select, fire?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function updateText(){
    alert(fontsize.options[fontsize.selectedIndex].value);
}

var fontsize = document.getElementById("fontsize");
fontsize.addEventListener('onChange','updateText',false);
```

This is my JavaScript to handle the selection of font sizes on my webpage. However, nothing happens when I select different values in the dropdown.

There are no errors in the console log, either.

So, my questions are:
1. Why won't it work ?
2. Why is using event delegation model recommended over `<select onchange="someMethod()">`

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

1. The event is called [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change), not `onchange`. `onchange` is the name of an HTML attribute and a DOM property.
2. You have to pass a function to `addEventListener`, not a string.

So

```
fontsize.addEventListener('change', updateText, false);
```

should work.

It seems you are mixing [inline](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html)or [traditional](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) event handlers with [advanced event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Equivalent inline event handler:

```
<select id="fontsize" onchange="updateText()">
```

or (don't do that):

```
fontsize.setAttribute('onchange', 'updateText()');
```

Unless you are only prototyping something, using inline event handlers is generally not a good idea, see below.

Equivalent traditional event handler:

```
fontsize.onchange = updateText;
```

---

> Why is using event delegation model recommended over `<select onchange="someMethod()">`

This has *nothing* to do with [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation). Event delegation is a concept independent from the way the event handlers are bound. For a practical reason not to use inline event handlers, see my answer here [onclick="" vs event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler/21975639#21975639).

I also recommend to read the [articles on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) which in my opinion explain everything you need to know about event handlers.

Comment: I am not mixing them. I always use the `addEventListener`. The question is : why does everyone recommend that ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild: Mixing in the sense of you are using one as if it were the other. E.g. you are using onchange which is an attribute/property of HTML/DOM elements, not an event, and you are passing a string instead of a function. If you follow the links, you will get a pretty good idea about the advantages and disadvantages of each of those methods. I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it should be

```
fontsize.addEventListener('change', updateText, false);
```

Not `onChange`.