# How do I clear inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I've been fiddling with this for a while but it won't work and I can't figure out why. Please help. Here is what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>lala</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 onmouseover="go('The dog is in its shed')" onmouseout="clear()">lalala</h1>
    <div id="goy"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function go(what) {
        document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = what;
    }
    function clear() {
        document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = "";
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The mouseover works and displays the text in the div, but when I move the mouse out of the h1 tag, the text stays there and I don't know why, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196. In your case, `clear` refers to `document.clear`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.clear

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the global symbol `clear` is already in use and your function doesn't succeed in overriding it. If you change that name to something else (I used `blah`), it works just fine:

Version using `clear` which fails:

```js
function go(what) {
    document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = what;
}
function clear() {
    document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<h1 onmouseover="go('The dog is in its shed')" onmouseout="clear()">lalala</h1>
<div id="goy"></div>
```

Version using `blah` which works:

```js
function go(what) {
    document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = what;
}
function blah() {
    document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<h1 onmouseover="go('The dog is in its shed')" onmouseout="blah()">lalala</h1>
<div id="goy"></div>
```

This is a great illustration of the fundamental principal: Avoid global variables wherever possible. The global namespace in browsers is *incredibly* crowded, and when conflicts occur, you get weird bugs like this. Now that JavaScript modules are supported in all major environments, you can use those to avoid creating globals and possibly conflicting with them: Top-level declarations in modules aren't globals, they only have module scope (similar to the old way of doing this where you'd wrap all your code in an inline-invoked function).

A corollary to that is to not use old-style `onxyz=...` attributes to hook up event handlers, because they require globals. Instead, hook things up with code:

```html
<h1 id="the-header">lalala</h1>
<div id="goy"></div>
<script type="module">
// Top-level declarations in modules aren't globals, so this
// `clear` doesn't conflict with the global `clear`
const header = document.getElementById("the-header");
header.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    go("The dog is in its shed");
});
header.addEventListener("mouseout", clear);

function go(what) {
    document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = what;
}
function clear() {
    document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was getting so frustrated. This works perfectly now. Also thanks for the quick response.

Comment: errors from not knowing globals are unfortunately difficult to debug in many languages.

Comment: @aaaaaa - Thankfully here in 2023 we can use modules to avoid creating globals and thus having the kinds of problems the OP did with conflicts.

Comment: Sure, but typically the people who encounter these issues aren't familiar with those tools yet

Answer (score 2):

```
const destroy = container => {
  document.getElementById(container).innerHTML = '';
};
```

> Faster previous

```
const destroyFast = container => {
  const el = document.getElementById(container);
  while (el.firstChild) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The h1 tags unfortunately do not receive the onmouseout events.

The simple Javascript snippet below will work for all elements and uses only 1 mouse event.

Note: "The borders in the snippet are applied to provide a visual demarcation of the elements."

```js
document.body.onmousemove = function(){ move("The dog is in its shed"); };

document.body.style.border = "2px solid red";
document.getElementById("h1Tag").style.border = "2px solid blue";

function move(what) {
    if(event.target.id == "h1Tag"){ document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = "what"; } else { document.getElementById("goy").innerHTML = ""; }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1Tag">lalala</h1>
<div id="goy"></div>
```

This can also be done in pure CSS by adding the hover selector css property to the h1 tag.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this. a clean and simple solution using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/ma2Yd/

```
    <h1 onmouseover="go('The dog is in its shed')" onmouseout="clear()">lalala</h1>
    <div id="goy"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
       $("h1").on('mouseover', function() {
          $("#goy").text('The dog is in its shed');
       }).on('mouseout', function() {
          $("#goy").text("");
       });
   });
```

Comment: clean and simple using jQuery but still uses inline js :P

Comment: I don't see a `jQuery` tag anywhere. From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*