# Why removeChild faster than innerHTML = ' '?

Tags: javascript

I have a two functions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51836513/8724512) to another question:

1.

```
const destroy = container => {
  document.getElementById(container).innerHTML = '';
};
```

2. 

```
const destroyFast = container => {
  const el = document.getElementById(container);
  while (el.firstChild) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
};
```

Why second func is faster than first func?

Comment: Do you have some kind of experimental results that suggest the second one faster?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ no, i just looked at the answer and asked

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb, `innerHtml` is slow because the browser needs to reparse the html (even though it is being set to `''`). `removeChild`, however, directly modifies the DOM without any parsing needed. Therefore `removeChild` is faster.