# Clear a paragraph using document.getElementById in HTML

Tags: javascript

I am making a calculator in HTML. I want to clear the result using the Clear button. But the thing does not work.

This is my HTML code for the clear button:

```
<button onclick="clear()">C</button>
```

This is my Javascript code for this function:

```
function clear()
{
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=" ";//text is the ID of the paragraph tag which holds the string which the user has passed
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML=" ";//answer is the ID of the paragraph tag which shows the answer
}
```

Please Help me out. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The code that you posted looks OK. Please share more context

Comment: Do the ids match? Can‘t see any error

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and concerns, but I knew that this thing was working with my rest code. The answer given by mpm helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in this question([How do I clear inner HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22593759/12907088))
you‘re overwriting `document.clear`, which might lead to errors.

Consider choosing another name for your function.

Comment: @AgastyaGarg  if it is working then please accept the answer