# How the does scope differ between these three ways of listening for events?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Assuming the function `doSomething()` is defined in the same place, does the function's scope when it is executed differ between these three methods of listening for events?

```
<body onload="doSomething();">
document.body.onload = doSomething;
document.body.addEventListener('load', doSomething);
```

Aside from attributes only being able to contain one "listener" compared to `addEventListener()`, are there any other differences between listening for events in these three ways? (such as passed in parameters, or the value of `this`?)

Comment: Well, in the attribute code you're obviously neither passing a `this` value nor the event to `doSomething()` …

Comment: While not relevant to your question, the third one wont do anything. You need to bind to the `'load'` event, rather than `'onload'`

Comment: @enhzflep Oops, that was a typo. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @enhzflep Though, difficult to debug typos like that wouldn't arise if JavaScript were stronly typed like AS3. My "fix": https://twitter.com/IQAndreas/status/453754209582583808

Comment: @IQAndreas - I personally, wouldn't consider that an improvement. You still have to remember that the 'on' prefix doesn't apply when using addEventListener. While it is true that you get the benefit of having a bunch of handler names in a block, which may aid in identifying a single errant one, it's an awful lot more typing (read: code-bloat) for something that consequently runs ever so slightly more slowly. That said - it's an approach that wouldn't suit me, since I can remember them (or lookup the names very quickly). Other's mileage would obviously vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onload="doSomething();"` is *similar* to

```
document.body.onload = function(event) { 
    doSomething();
};
```

Inside the event handler itself, `this` refers to the element the handler is bound to, but inside `doSomething`, `this` will refer to `window`, [since you are calling the function "normally"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call). `doSomething` doesn't have access to the event object either. You have to pass `this` and `event` along if you want `doSomething` work the same as in the other cases:

```
onload="doSomething.call(this, event);"
```

**Note**: Properties of `document`, ancestor DOM elements and the DOM element itself [are in the scope for the *event handler*](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html) (not `doSomething`), which can lead to very confusing behavior. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196)  for more info.

`document.body.onload = doSomething;` and `document.body.addEventListener('load', doSomething);` are equivalent in terms of scope and context, and they don't have this strange scope behavior that inline event handlers have.

[More information about the different ways can be found on quirksmode.org.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Comment: Just being pedantic here. After some testing, there seems to be one slight difference to what you called _"similar to"_. It seems like when placed in the `body.onload` variable, the callback function is stored as a named function (as opposed to your anonymous function). See: http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/ytW6B/1/

Comment: Shouldn't affect the scope though, I just included that point for perfection's sake.