# Why can't I call a function named clear from an onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to create a simple calculator,  when a button is clicked its value is shown in the text field and the button "C" should clear the text field but its onclick="clear()" is not working??

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <style>
            #button{
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function fill(val){
                document.getElementById("field").value+=val;
            }
            function clear(){
                document.getElementById("field").value="";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <table>
            <tr><input type="text" name="field" id="field" size="8"/></tr>
        <%! int k = 1; %>
        <% for(int i=0;i<3;i++){ %>
        <tr> <%
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){ %>
            <td><input type="button" id="button" onclick="fill(this.value)" value="<%=k++%>" /></td>
          <%  } %>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
        <tr>

<!--here onclick="clear()" is not working?? -->

            <td><input type="button" id="button" value="C" onclick="clear()"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="button" value="0" onclick="fill(this.value)"</td>
            <td><input type="submit" id="button" value="="</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a client side problem. Don't show us server side code. Get the HTML output.

Comment: You aren't closing the button tag. The wonky syntax highlighting should be a clue

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Well, as far as I can see your last two inputs are a disaster: the first one is not closed, while the second one is not closed and has a caotic value: `value="="`, you should start by fixing these first.

Comment: Use different Ids. Thats why it called id. Put your script at the body end and not in the head. Some times you trigger someting that not load (body) yet.

Comment: You could show an alert dialog to test if clear() is being called at all.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001908/how-the-does-scope-differ-between-these-three-ways-of-listening-for-events

Comment: http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Intrinsic event attributes (like `onclick`) are horrible. Internally they implement [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with):

> Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues.

Consequently, you are actually calling [`document.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear) instead of your global `clear()`.

The quick fix for this is to rename the function to something else or explicitly call `window.clear()`.

The better solution is to bind your event handlers with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of intrinsic event attributes.

[image]

Comment: Intrinsic handlers have a number of objects on their scope chain, including the current element and the document, and possibly ancestor elements (e.g. form control handlers have the form on their scope chain). Whether *with* is used for this or not is moot. It's not always clear which identifier will be resolved on those elements (e.g. ID is always on the current target, action will be on a parent form, className might be anywhere) or on the global/window object. Better naming of global identifiers (e.g. less likely to clash, more descriptive) also helps.

Comment: Woah... What a thing. Haven't known this before.

Comment: _Consequently, you are actually calling document.clear() instead of your global clear()._ - why is `document` there? Do you know how is this `with` functionality working with `onclick` like attributes?

Comment: @Maximus — Because, as the screenshot shows, there is a With Block that uses the document object.

Comment: @Quentin, I can see that :). I'm wondering why it's using `document` as a `with object`

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML has problems, but the reason your function is not working is because of its name "clear", which is already defined by `document.clear()`.

Change the name of that function to something like `clearField()` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

`clear` is a reference to a (deprecated) [`document.clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/clear) function. This has precedence to (shadows) the function you created, because of the scope that is created specifically for `onXXXXX` attributes in HTML.

This peculiar scope is only active in the script that is provided to this attribute. As soon as execution moves into the JavaScript code that is defined in `script` tags, this scope "overload" is gone.

So for instance, your code would work again, if you would first call another function, and then let *that* function call your `clear` function. Like so:

```js
function clear() {
    alert("my clear() was called");
}

function helper() {
    clear();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="helper()">Clear!</button>
```

#### Background / Source

The scope that is created for executing the script that is passed to an `onXXXX` attribute is defined in the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes:js-ordinaryfunctioncreate-2):

> #### scope
>
> 1. Let *realm* be *settings object*'s Realm.
> 2. Let *scope* be *realm*.[[GlobalEnv]].
> 3. If *eventHandler* is an element's event handler, then set *scope* to [NewObjectEnvironment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-newobjectenvironment)(*document*, true, *scope*).
>    (Otherwise, *eventHandler* is a Window object's event handler.)
> 4. If *form owner* is not null, then set *scope* to [NewObjectEnvironment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-newobjectenvironment)(*form owner*, true, *scope*).
> 5. If *element* is not null, then set scope to [NewObjectEnvironment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-newobjectenvironment)(*element*, true, *scope*).
> 6. Return *scope*.

These steps describe how the scope is defined, and this includes which identifiers are bound to which properties. And so we see in step 3 that `document` is added to the scope, which means that `document` properties become accessible via global names. Similarly, the scope may be extended further. For instance, in step 5, the element's properties also become accessible as globals.

Here is an example of that latter point:

```js
var id = 12; // global variable
console.log(id); // 12
```

```html
<button id="this-is-me" onclick="console.log(id)">click me</button>
```

#### Conclusion

This scope issue can be confusing, certainly when `document` is an object with many (and many obscure) properties.

All the more reason to avoid using `onXXX` attributes in your HTML. Best practice is to add event handlers in the main script, using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).