# Counters show permanently even if onclick

Tags: javascript, local-storage, counter

I have the following entry in a table:

```
<tr>
    <td class="right-middle user">Name</td>
    <td class="right-middle done">
        <div onload="clickCounter()" id="result"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="right-middle check">
        <img src="img/check.png" onclick="clickCounter()">
    </td>
    <td class="right-middle undone">
        <div onload="addcounter()" id="result2"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="right-middle uncheck">
        <img src="img/uncheck.png" onclick="addCounter()">
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the following javascript:

```
function clickCounter() {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;


function addCounter() {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcounts) {
            localStorage.clickcounts = Number(localStorage.clickcounts) + 1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcounts = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcounts;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}

document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcounts;
```

I want both counters to be displayed on the screen all the time, even after refreshing the page without having to press the button to see the value. I have used this bits of code out of the table and they work fine. Can anyone help me understand why do the counters not display all the time on the screen?

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: @BasvanStein — Stackoverflow has supported [inline live demos](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for over a year. There's no need to depend on a third party site to host parts of a question or answer any more.

Comment: @Quentin That is also fine of course, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div elements don't have `load` events. Only elements which get their content from other URLs (like images and frames) and the document itself do.

Since you are using intrinsic event attributes ([problematic though they are]([Why can't I call a function named clear from an onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-is-the-2nd-function-inside-script-not-working/31613889#31613889)
)), this would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Either:

- Just run the functions in a script element that appears after the elements you want to interact with *or*
- Use the document's load event

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g334tgby/1/ i have asked  a similar question a few weeks ago and i was provided with this working fiddle which i could implement in ohter cases. here onload worked with div

Comment: @AlexResiga — No, it doesn't. I [changed](http://jsfiddle.net/g334tgby/2/) the function to erase the content of the body. If the load event on the div worked, the body would immediately vanish, but it doesn't until you click the button.

Comment: oh, i see.i'm quite a beginner so could you show me how to make the counter display on the screen all the time? a fiddle could really help

Answer (score 1):

The `onload()` event cannot be used on any other element but a limited set of tags: `<body>` `<frame>` `<frameset>` `<iframe>` `<img>` `<link>` `<script>`