# Value is not defined when trying to call with function with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

When im trying to send(onclick) value to toggle_sprint() function i get error that value is not defined. Why is it not defined? I thought it got defined when i put value="false" but apparently not.

```
<div class="select">
    <div id="toggle_sprint" value="false" onclick="toggle_sprint(value);" >Toggle Sprint</div>

</div>
```

Comment: When you click it, it's looking for a variable called `value` in your scope, and it does not exist.

Comment: Divs don't have value attributes

Answer (score 2):

There is no `value` attribute for div elements… and div elements aren't designed to be interactive so you're creating a bunch of accessibility issues by slapping `onclick` on a div.

Additionally, your use of an [intrinsic event attribute means that `toggle_sprint()` probably isn't what you think it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute/31613889#31613889).

Start by writing good HTML.

Use `data-*` attributes to provide data just for your JS. Use buttons to provide things to click on and trigger JS.

Then bind your event handlers with JavaScript.

```js
    document.getElementById("toggle_sprint").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      toggle_sprint(this.dataset.value);
    });

    function toggle_sprint(arg) {
      console.log(arg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <button type="button" id="toggle_sprint" data-value="false">Toggle Sprint</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note that `addEventListener` doesn't work in IE below 9.