# Moving code from PHP to .js file, code not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I picked up a project that another developer built. He has some of the JavaScript on the actual php page which is making debugging difficult.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="doFunction(event)">Done</button>
```

I have tried to move it to a javascript file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function doFunction(e){}
});
```

and removing it from the PHP page but now it's not firing. Why is it not working now and how do I fix it?

Comment: did you load the external file? `<script src="yourcode.js"></script>`? the browser isn't going to magically realize that you moved the code elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I put it in a .js file being used already.

Comment: `e` is undefined within your `.ready()`. I suggest you look at your js console for errors.

Comment: Is it after the jquery library include?

Comment: Did you leave the `<button type="submit" onclick="doFunction(event)">Done</button>` or is that the previous solution that you've removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined `function doFunction(e){}` inside another function.

That *locally scopes* it. It is not a global. It is not accessible from `onclick` attributes (since they aren't defined inside the same function).

Don't use `onclick` attributes, they have [many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-is-the-2nd-function-inside-script-not-working/31613889#31613889), bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead.

Since you are using jQuery:

```
$('button').on('click', doFunction);
```

You can use a more specific selector if you like.

That said, almost anything you want to do with a submit button is clicked is better done when a form is submitted.

```
$('form').on('submit', doFunction);
```

Comment: How can I make it globally accessible?

Comment: Don't. Globals are evil.

Comment: @DavidTunnell define `function doFunction(e)` in the global scope and not inside the `$( document ).ready` function call. If you don't want to pollute the global scope, you can define an object in the global scope with `doFunction` as one of it's properties.

Comment: As a trick, you can do : `window['doFunction'] = function(e){}`
But this is bad practice

Comment: @DavidTunnell, While I agree with the sentiment of Quentin on not making it global, some projects in the real world don't have the budgets to do things the right way.  this project may have hundreds of these calls baked into the HTML.  And yes, I'd use Robin's method or `window.doFunction = function(e){ ... };`