# How do I pass a string variable through this java script function and then into getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

My objective is to create a function that can be called at different points on a page to make certain `<p>` elements disappear and reappear. The viewer will be able to click on key words in the paragraph to make elements below it appear.

I have done something similar in another code block, but it requires me to make a new function every time I use it. And I may potentially have 15-20 times I need to call it on one page.

Below is the code I have written. The "state" is what I am using to make sure the processor is getting into my loops. I've had some experience with Java but I'm not super knowledgeable so I need small things like this.

This works perfectly, but only for one time. Because I have to set the variable "hidden" as the specific id of the object I want, it makes it a single use kind of thing. That would mean I need multiple functions. I would like to just pass the name of the id into the function as a parameter so that the function could be called for different objects.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>

    a {color: red; }

    </style>

</head>  

<body>

<p id="currentState">Not set yet</p>

<p>Within this paragraph, <a onclick="myFunction()">THIS</a> is what you click.</p>

<p id="hidden1">This is supposed to be hidden</p>



<script>
    var state;

    function myFunction() {

        var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden1");

        if (hidden.style.display != "none"){
            hidden.style.display = "none";
            state = "State: Visible";
        }

        else if (hidden.style.display == "none"){
            hidden.style.display = "block";
            state = "State: Hidden";
        }

        document.getElementById("currentState").innerHTML = state;
    } 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is what I keep trying to do to fix my problem, but nothing seems to work. I'm not sure if its because the getElementById() doesn't recognize my variable as a string or if I'm not declaring the parameter correctly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>

    a {color: red; }

    </style>

</head>  

<body>

<p id="currentState">Not set yet</p>

<p>Within this paragraph, <a onclick="myFunction("hidden1")">THIS</a> is what you click.</p>

<p id="hidden1">This is supposed to be hidden</p>



<script>

    var state;

    function myFunction(name) {

        var hidden = document.getElementById(name);

        if (hidden.style.display != "none"){
            hidden.style.display = "none";
            state = "State: Visible";

        }

        else if (hidden.style.display == "none"){
            hidden.style.display = "block";
            state = "State: Hidden";

        }


        document.getElementById("currentState").innerHTML = state;



    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think something is off in this line:
    `<a onclick="myFunction("hidden1")">THIS</a>`
That seems to be when my program says I have a syntax error. I'm not sure what that is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you put a sample of your "p" elements, and the elements to be hidden?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <a onclick="myFunction("hidden1")">
> ```

The first `"` starts the value of the HTML attribute.

The second `"` ends the value of the HTML attribute.

If you want a `"` as **data** in an attribute delimited with `"` then you have to use an entity such as `&quot;`.

Alternatively, switch to using `'`.

Better yet, [bind your event handlers using JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). That will [separate your markup from your logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and save you from some of [the weirdness that is intrinsic event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute/31613889#31613889).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using jQuery:

In your html:

```
... <a href="#" class="hiddenTrigger" data-target="hidden1">THIS</a> ...

... <p id="hidden1"> ...
```

In your JavaScript:

```
$('.hiddenTrigger').click(function () {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('#'+target).show();
});
```