# Defining Javascript/JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, function

What is the proper way of defining javascript functions, inside

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});
```

or just outside.

What I have is this :

```js
$(function() {
  var html = '<div class ="new1" ><img id = "new2" onclick = "showPage(' + id + 
      ');" class = "' + id + 
      '" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/blankpageQ.jpg")" />' + 
      i + '</div>');
  $(".pageListQuiz")
    .children('div')
    .eq(numOfPages - 1)
    .append(html);

  function showPage() {
    //some actions
  }
});
```

and clicking on the appended image throws an exception :

```
Unhandled exception at line 3, column 1 in script block

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'showPage' is undefined

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

(The js code is embedded from my c# code.).
Everything works fine if I place `showPage()` outside anyway. I just wonder why its not working when I put it inside because I also have functions placed inside that are just working fine.

Comment: Depends on what you're wrapping in `ready`. If some code that depends on the DOM, it should be wrapped in `ready()`, other code can be move outside of `ready`. Also, if the JS is included at the end of `<body>` there's no need of `ready`.

Comment: that depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: `$(document).ready` is irrelevant if you're not using jQuery.

Comment: could you give me some examples please. I'm still new to js and is not yet very familiar with it. @Tusher

Comment: I believe OP means, what is better, write an anonymous function as handler or create a function and pass its reference to event handler.

Comment: I have updated my question. kindly check.

Comment: @JanLeeYu If you declare a function inside `ready()` callback, it will **not** be accessible from outside of the `ready()` callback. If you want to call this from HTML or other places(_outside of `ready`_), move it out of `ready()`.

Comment: You can also try having a generic handler for all added images. You can add a class say `newImage` and have code `$(document).on("click", ".newImage", function(event){ // Do your stuff here })`.

Comment: Thank you for spending time to answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to read about scope and context: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### @Tushar's Approach

Idea: Create functions and use `$(document).ready()` to execute necessary functions.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g1eu3xfq/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
})

function showPage(el){
  console.log(el);
}
```

---

#### My Approach

Idea: You can have a event handler, instead of setting `onclick` attribute. Benefit of this approach is, you can have your markup generation logic clean.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g1eu3xfq/1/)

---

Note, you can merge both approaches. Its better to declare all functions and then use `$(document).ready()` as an initialization function. This will just call different functions. If you choose to use `event handlers/delegates`, you can export all events to different file as well and just call it.

Answer (score 1):

Function delarations are scoped just like `var` statements.

If you define a function inside another function, then you can only access it within the scope of that function.

If you want to access it as a global (which is what an intrinsic event attribute like `onclick=` does), then you either need to define it as a global or copy it into the global scope.

In this case, however, you should avoid using globals. You should also avoid using [intrinsic event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-is-the-2nd-function-inside-script-not-working/31613889#31613889) and building HTML by mashing together strings.

This is untested but should give you the idea.

```
$(function () {

  var id = "something";
  var numOfPages = 2;

  var html = $("<div/>")
    .addClass("new1")
    .append(
      $("<img/>")
        .attr("id", "new2")
        .on("click", showPage.bind(null, id))
        .addClass(id)
        .attr("src", '@Url.Content("~/Images/blankpageQ.jpg")')
    );
  $(".pageListQuiz")
    .children('div')
    .eq(numOfPages - 1)
    .append(html);

  function showPage(id) { 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you create an `<img>` element in the HTML of the page. When it is clicked, `showPage()` is called. Since the function is called from the global scope (as it is called from a click on the HTML, which goes into the global scope), the global scope is looked up for the existence of the `showPage()` function. However, it does not exist inside the global scope; it exists only in the scope of your `$(function() {})` function.

If you want to access `showPage()` from the global scope, you need to make sure it is available there. You can either do that by defining it outside your `$(function() {})` construction (a `function` declaration creates a new scope), or by defining a var outside your `$(function() {})` construction and assigning the `showPage()` function to that var. For example:

```
var showPage;

$(function() {
    // Assign the function showPage() to the var showPage:
    showPage = function showPage() {
        // You function body.
    }
});

// showPage is now available in the global scope.
```

Either solution is OK. Maybe you could read up a bit on [Javascript scopes and closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). That will help you understand what's happening here.