# Prevent link from opening by returning false - not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, hyperlink

This should be a simple one, but I haven't been able to find an answer

I have a link that triggers a function.

```
<a href="someplace.html" onclick="myfunction()"</a>
```

If I want to prevent the link from opening, I need the function to return false, right?

```
function myfunction() {
  // some code
  return false;
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I might be missing something essential here, but please help me out.

Why is this not working:
http://codepen.io/lukastillmann/pen/aNmZbx?editors=1010

Comment: `onclick="return myfunction()"` would do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return false **from the event handler function**.

Your event handler function:

1. calls myfunction()
2. … and that's it, it has no return statement.

`myfunction` has a return statement, but it isn't the event handler function. It is another function called from the event handler function.

```
onclick="return myfunction()"
```

---

Modern code wouldn't use `onclick` attributes which [have horrible gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613889/19068) and violate [several best practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

```
function myfunction(e) {
  // some code
  e.preventDefault();
}

document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", myfunction);
```

Comment: I did not know that gotcha about `onclick`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if there's an uncaught error in the JavaScript function it'll effectively fall through and jump to the link.

Comment: "return myfunction()" does the trick. Thank you!

I had actually tried using the event listener and e.preventDefault:
http://codepen.io/lukastillmann/pen/oxzrVL?editors=1010

But this is still not working. Any Ideas?

Comment: @lukastillmann — `preventDefault` is a function. You have to call it, not just mention it. You lost the `()`.

Comment: thanks @Quentin and everyone. Somehow this has been driving me nuts for days.