# is 'slot' a reserve word in newer version of ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

It's an issue with google chrome version 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit). I tried running a simple html file and it throws the error 'slot.testFun is not a function' when I used the word 'slot'.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="slot.testFun();">Click Here</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var slot = {
            testFun: function(){
                console.log('clicked');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are no conflicts with this variable in our code. It's just the browser, not allowing the variable name in this latest version.

If you use any other name except the word 'slot', it works fine.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gikonediru/1/edit?html,output — Your code runs without any problems when I test it.

Comment: "it throws the same error" — The same error as what?

Comment: @Quentin - hate to tell you this, but your jsbin throws `Uncaught TypeError: slot.testFun is not a function` error - in chrome 53 (windows 10 64bit)

Comment: changing slot to slu .... I mean, slit, works fine

Comment: @JaromandaX I fear that any alternative spelling ('u', 'i', 'a') is a derogatory term. Let's make it `zlot` ;D

Comment: updated my description

Comment: Related: [My answer in "onclick=“” vs event handler"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't an ECMAScript issue, it is a DOM issue.

The [slot attribute](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-slot) has a corresponding `slot` property, and [`onclick` attributes do stupid things with `with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute/31613889#31613889) so you are effectively calling `this.slot.testFun()` because it finds `slot` (which defaults to being an empty string) before it gets to the right scope.

`slot` is a new addition to the DOM and support for `slot` is new in Chrome 53. It does not appear in Chrome 52 and might not have made it even into the latest version of other browsers.

The solution: Avoid intrinsic event attributes. Bind event handlers with DOM instead. That protects you from his clash and future-proofs you from future additions to the DOM.

```
<a href="#">Click Here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var slot = {
        testFun: function(){
            console.log('clicked');
        }
    }
    document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", slot.testFun);
</script>
```

Comment: or use `window.slot.testFun` in on*** attributes :p

Comment: @JaromandaX — That would work too, but is far away from best practise. Globals are best avoided in general. Separation of concerns is generally a good idea.

Comment: but why in latest version of chrome only ?
It works fine in latest version of firefox. I am facing this issue after I updated my chrome browser.

Comment: @SantoshPradhan Because the  `slot` property is quite new and only supported in the latest releases. FF has the same problems with more common property names like `id` or `className` etc