# Why is the evt passed from an onSubmit undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to get the onSubmit to be prevented in a form submission.
I have 2 questions.

1) Where is the e parameter being passed in from?

2) Why is e undefined and therefore not correctly preventing the default action? The page refreshes each time which is the action that I'm trying to prevent

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onSubmit={func}>
      <input type='text'/>
      <button type='submit'/>
    </form>
    <script>
      let func = (e) => {
        console.log('BEING CALLED')
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where is the e parameter being passed in from?

Nowhere

> Why is e undefined and therefore not correctly preventing the default action?

Because the function isn't being called.

---

> ```
> onSubmit={func}
> ```

Your JavaScript function:

1. Starts a block (which has no practical effect)
2. Mentions a function name (which has no effect because you didn't call it, combine it with an operator, or anything)
3. Ends the block

All for a grand total of nothing.

---

The correct syntax for an onsubmit attribute would be:

```
onsubmit="func(event);"
```

… in which you actually call `func` and you pass it the argument you are trying to pass it. (Intrinsic event attributes get an argument called `event` automatically).

---

Binding events with HTML is considered bad practise, and [they come with nasty gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613889/19068). It is generally prefered to bind event handlers with JS.

```
document.querySelector("form")
        .addEventListener("submit", func);
```

Now `func` is the event handler itself, and it gets the event object as the first argument because that is what event handlers get.

---

Note that arrow functions are:

1. Anonymous, which makes them less useful to work with in debuggers
2. Capture the current value of `this` (which is usually unwelcome for event handlers since it stops you using `this` to get the element the handler was bound to).

Function declarations are generally preferable.

Comment: wow I never know js on* tag in html form always use `event` variable, I tried using e but never succeed. This's sad TBH. Anyway thanks!