# Function defined in another .js file not found in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to Javascript and NodeJS.

Here is my website's code structure:

```
|source
|   | stylesheets
|   |    | index.styl
|   | templates
|        | default.jade
|        | homepage.jade
|static
|   | [.css generated]
|
|server.js
|package.json
|file.js
```

And here is `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express')
    , logger = require('morgan')
    , app = express()
    , templateHome = require('jade').compileFile(__dirname + '/source/templates/homepage.jade')        

app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'))

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        var html = templateHome({ title: 'Home' })
        res.send(html)
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000))
})
```

My second `.js` file contains a simple function that should be accessed once my user clicks a button in my home page defined in `Jade` like such:

```
block content
    button(onclick='downloadFile()') Click me
```

But it seems that the function is not defined in the current scope, even though it is defined in `file.js`. What do I have to add in order to take my other `.js` files into account?

Comment: *But it seems that the function is not defined in the current scope* — You haven't shown it to be defined at all.

Comment: It is defined in `file.js` that is in my project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the script using a `<script>` element. Specify the URL to the JavaScript file using the `src` attribute. You will need to give the file a URL, this is probably most simply done by moving it to the `static/` directory, alongside the CSS.

```
<script src="/file.js"></script>
```

---

Do be aware that a program which runs on the server and a program which runs in the browser are two different programs, even if they are written in the same programming language. If `file.js` contains JS that is expected to run on the server and not in the browser then you will need to take another approach. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) addresses the issues in passing values between server and client.

---

Also note that `onclick` and other intrinsic event attributes have [nasty gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute/31613889#31613889), are generally considered less than [best practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), and should generally be replaced by [binding handlers with JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thank you very much, I do understand the distinction between client-side JS and server-side JS.
But I believe my problem is related to the inclusion of another JS file in my project. If I have a function with a simple alert in `file.js` and if I call said function in `server.js`, the function is not defined.

When I include `file.js` in the html page that requires it, the file is not found.

Comment: Since `alert` is a browser specific function, then of course it is `undefined` on the server.

Comment: If you are getting a `404 Not Found` then you need to do what I said in the first paragraph of this answer and give it a URL.

Comment: Of course, I do include my js file like such in `homepage.jade`: `script(src="file.js")` which is an equivalent to what you have proposed. Is this not the right way of doing it?

Comment: @Christopher — You've told the browser what URL to use, but you haven't configured the server so that that URL works. I refer you again to the first paragraph of this answer. The third sentence of it in particular.

Comment: You were right, I moved my script to the static folder and it now works. Your answer was very clear, thank you.