# onclick action not calling javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am expecting that the on button click action should popup the alert message. But I am unable to figure out the root cause that code doesn't work as expected.

**Here is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function click() {
alert("this is an alert");
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="click()" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your Javascript console for any errors…?

Comment: yes there are no errors in my console

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute/31613889#31613889

Comment: This is giving you error because 'click' is overridden by window.click method. Change name of click function like showMsg() and it will work fine. I have tested it and it is working fine. I am unable to post an answer because your question is on hold. Here is a codepen link https://codepen.io/upasanak/pen/GEXmvb

Comment: I see! wow thanks brother, newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `click()` function corresponding to button in JavaScript. Try using `window.click()`

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.click()" value="click me"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now, I could never remember typing window in before, but this definitely made it pop up.

Comment: You welcome....