# if else statement using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

How can I correct this code using javascript and html. Thanks in advance! 
please help me out of this problem.

```
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">
<input type="submit" onclick="submit()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        var q = document.getElementById('text1');
        var w = document.getElementById('text2');

        if (q > w) {
            console.log('q is greaterthan in w');
        } else{
            console.log('q is less that in w');
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to have your code do, and what's happening instead?

Comment: why do you -rep me :( I dont really know what is the syntax or code here :(

Comment: What is the problem? What does the console tell you? Are you sure `q` and `w` can be compared using the operator `>`?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute/31613889#31613889), but the question lacks a clear problem statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are comparing the DOM elements (input fields) themselves, not their values. In order to get the values and compare those, you have to actually get the `.value` property and treat them as Numbers (float or integer or whatever it's going to be).

```js
function submit() {
    var q = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text1').value);
    var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text2').value);

    if (q > w) {
        console.log('q is greater than w');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('q is less or equal than w');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">
<input type="submit" onclick="submit()">
```

Comment: Not me downvoting, but you have a spelling error in the second parseFLoat

Comment: Already noticed and fixed after dealing with this nonsense! ;)

Comment: @Connum thats what I mean bro, thankyou so much! :D

Comment: Glad to help. Even if there are obviously people thinking that my answer is not helpful at all... If you're expecting the textbox to hold text, not numbers, then just don't use the `parseFloat()`. But you still have to get the `.value` in order to compare the string.

Comment: what should I change in the parseFloat? Sorry for my litte problem for you, im really a beginner in this javascript.

Comment: just leave the `parseFloat()` out completely. It just converts a string to a float number.

Answer (score -2):

You have to get the value of the input like this: `document.getElementById('text1').value`

```
function submit() {
    var q = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    var w = document.getElementById('text2').value;

    if (q > w) {
        console.log('q is greaterthan in w');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('q is less that in w');
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do I have downvotes if this is a helpful answer? Haha.

Comment: Just your comment now - it happened to my answer as well and just happened again in another question. The answer to why people do this is: Because some people here are idiots. Maybe they have low self-esteem or other problems in their real lifes, who knows. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions