# Jquery predefined textarea wont clear

Tags: php, jquery, forms, textarea

Prefilling a textarea with data pulled from a DB.

`<textarea name="body" id="body" rows="5" cols="70"><? echo $body; ?></textarea>`

I have a clear button to make it easier for the user to wipe a large chunk of text without having to highlight and delete.

The button uses an `onclick="clear();"` function call.

Here is the function...

```
function clear() {
    $('#body').val('');
}
```

The problem is it wont clear the predefined text. It will only clear text typed in addition to the predefined text. Or if I manually remove the predefined text it works fine.

I need the field to show the value from the DB. Is there a way to accomplish this without echoing the DB value in a `<div>` above the field and refraining from pre-defining the ext in the textarea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your function to be something other than `clear()` and the rest is good. See [Why can't I call a function named clear from an onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute)

Alternatively use `.on('click', ...)` as I've demonstrated below by attaching the event listener to the button using the class `js-clear`.

```js
function myClear() {
  $('#body').val('');
}

$('.js-clear').on('click', function() {
  $('#body').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea name="body" id="body" rows="5" cols="70">test content</textarea><br>

<button onclick="myClear()">myClear</button>
<button class="js-clear">.on('click')</button>
```

Comment: @Sabyre All good. I had no idea about `document.clear()` until now either. Apparently its deprecated anyway https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-clear: `The clear(), captureEvents(), and releaseEvents() methods must do nothing.`