# Why does my javascript not output the total of four numbers in an html form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calculation

This is a small part of a larger project. Why does it not output the total of the four number and display in the fifth text box?

```
<body>
<form action="acknolcupcard" method="post" name="CupCard" id="CupCard" target="_self">
<p></p>

<input name="OneH1" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" onchange="calc"/>
<input name="OneH2" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" onchange="calc"/>
<input name="OneH3" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" onchange="calc"/>
<input name="OneH4" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" onchange="calc"/>


<label for="S1TotH"></label>
<input type="text" name="S1TotH" id="S1TotH" value="0" size= "10" maxlength= "10"/> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calc(){
var S1TotH =<br />
document.getElementById('OneH1').value +
document.getElementById('OneH2').value +
document.getElementById('OneH3').value +
document.getElementById('OneH4').value;

document.getElementById('S1TotH').value = S1TotH;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Is `var S1TotH =<br />` a copy/paste error?

Comment: The even handler function is never called. Notice also, that you're getting strings as a value, you'd might want to convert them to numbers before doing math with the values. And `gEBI` doesn't get element by name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add id as an attribute:

```
<input id="OneH1" name="OneH1" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" onchange="calc"/>
```

Also in order to call the method you should create a handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calc() {
    // This doesn't work since <br/> has no type (e.g. var S1TotH = '<br />')
    var S1TotH =<br />

    /* This values need to be stored in a variable or used in some way
    (e.g. var S1TotH = document.getElementById('OneH1').value + document...). But be careful because in this way you are concatenating the
    values, not adding them. If you want to add them you 
    should convert them to numbers (e.g. parseFloat(document.getElementById('OneH1').value)) */

    document.getElementById('OneH1').value +
    document.getElementById('OneH2').value +
    document.getElementById('OneH3').value +
    document.getElementById('OneH4').value;

    document.getElementById('S1TotH').value = S1TotH;
  }

  // use 'input' or 'change' event 
  document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {
      calc();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

## You don't call the function

Mentioning the name of a variable (even if the value of that variable is a function) doesn't **call** the function.

You need to put `(argument, list)` after it.

```
 onchange="calc()"
```

Intrinsic event attributes have a bunch of problems though (e.g [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute)) and are best avoided.

You could use a delegated event listener instead.

```js
function calc(event) {
  const input = event.target;
  console.log(input.value);
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("change", calc);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number">
  <input type="number">
</form>
```

---

## You have no `id`s

Then it will run, but error, because you are using `getElementById` without having elements with `id` attributes.

---

## You are concatenating not adding

Once you fix that, you will still not be adding up the values because `+` servers double duty as the concatenation operator and values are *strings*.

You need to convert them to numbers (e.g. with `parseFloat`).

Answer (score -1):

This code should work, use **oninput** instead of **onchange** for live changes reflect, I resolved few other errors too.

```html
<body>
<form action="acknolcupcard" method="post" name="CupCard" id="CupCard" target="_self">
<p></p>

<input name="OneH1" id="OneH1" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" oninput="calc()"/>
<input name="OneH2" id="OneH2" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" oninput="calc()"/>
<input name="OneH3" id="OneH3" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" oninput="calc()"/>
<input name="OneH4" id="OneH4" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" oninput="calc()"/>


<label for="S1TotH"></label>
<input type="text" name="S1TotH" id="S1TotH" value="0" size= "10" maxlength= "10"/> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calc(){
var S1TotH = 
document.getElementById('OneH1').value +
document.getElementById('OneH2').value +
document.getElementById('OneH3').value +
document.getElementById('OneH4').value;

document.getElementById('S1TotH').value = S1TotH;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Above code will concate the values as these are **strings** values so far so you need to use the **[parseInt()](https://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)** function if you want to convert it into numbers

Comment: Yes, it is concatenating. I will add the parsint() but I am a bit confused at I thought that using type= "number" ensured that it went through as a number without having to do that.

Comment: @RoyCaswell no brother it won't, It will just tweak the control as a spinner but the value still be in string