# How can HTML inline handlers access the global window object and variables inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, scope, dom-events, global-scope

I was testing a piece of code. I had a function named `write`, and I used a button with the inline `onclick` handler to run `write()`.

```js
function write(text) {
  alert(text)
}
```

```html
<button onclick='write("Some text")'>
  Write
</button>
```

To my surprise, `write()` actually executed `document.write()`. To be sure, I tested it with a few more functions.

```js
function write(text) {
  alert(text)
}
```

```html
<button onclick='console.log(body)'>
  document.body
</button>
```

Then, I wondered if they could access `window`. It turned out that they can. But, `document.window` is `undefined`.

```js
console.log(document.window)

/*

Note that this example may not work due to StackSnippets using iframes

*/
```

```html
<button onclick='window.open()'>
  Open blank page
</button>
```

```js
function doSomething(text) {
  console.log(text)
}
```

```html
<button onclick='doSomething("Some text")'>
  doSomething
</button>
```

So, my question is, why can inline event handlers access properties of `window`, even though `document` is the global scope, and `document.window` is `undefined`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler/21975639#21975639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In inline event handlers, if `this.property` exists, it defaults to that. If not, it falls back to `document.property`. If even that doesn't exist, finally, it executes that code in the global `window` scope.

### Some examples

In this example, the inline handler defaults to `document` as the global scope.

```js
document.someProperty = 'something'

var someProperty = 'something else'
```

```html
<button onclick='console.log(someProperty)'>
  Button
</button>
```

In this example, it defaults to `window`.

```js
var someProperty = 'something'
```

```html
<button onclick='console.log(someProperty)'>
  Button
</button>
```

In yet another example, it defaults to `this`, which is the element.

```html
<button style='color: red' onclick='console.log(style.color)'>
  Button
</button>
```