# Javascript firebase code results in "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase

error is SignUp is not a function, can't see why

```
    <form>

<label for="Email">Email</label><input type="text" id="Email">

<label for="Password">Password</label><input type="text" id="Password">

<button onclick="SignUp()" id="SignUp">SignUp</button>

    </form>



        <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>

<script>
  const auth = firebase.auth();
</script>

<script>
  function SignUp() {
      var email = document.getElementById("Email");
      var password = document.getElementById("Password");
      const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
  }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intrinsic event attributes do [horrible things with scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute).

When you use the identifier `SignUp` it searches up the DOM from the `<button>` the `onclick` attribute belongs to.

The first thing it finds with that name is the button itself — because it has the `id` `SignUp`.

The button is not a function, hence the error.

---

The quick and dirty solution to this is to rename either the function or the button.

The better solution is to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the techniques we were stuck with in the 1990s.

Comment: "The quick and dirty solution to this is to rename either the function or the button" thanks just for my understanding there's no other way to reference the function with a path ?