# Getting SyntaxError and ReferenceError but no clue why

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm trying to get into javascript and wrote a short script. What I get when I start the script is "Uncaught SyntaxError: function statement requires a name" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: retrieve is not defined". I don't see why my functions don't work properly. Does anyone have a clue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function save(){
                alert("in");
                var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                localStorage.setItem("text",name);
                document.getElementById("out").value=name;
            }
            
            function retrieve(){
                alert("in retr");
                var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("text");
                if (retrievedData){
                    document.getElementById("name").value=retrievedData;
                }
            }
            
            function delete(){
                document.getElementById("name").value="";
                localStorage.removeItem("text");
            }
        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="retrieve()">
    
        <form >
            <h1>Enter your name</h1>
            <input id ="name" type="text" name="name_input"/>
            <input type="button" name="save" value="save" onclick="save()"/>
            <input type="button" name="rm" value="remove" onclick="delete()"/><br>
            <input type="text" name="out" id="out"/>
        </form>
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: `delete` is a reserved keyword. Rename it to something else and the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the console. Look at the error messages **in order**.

Deal with the first problem first.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'delete'

[`delete` is the name of an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), you can't use it as the name of a function.

Rename that function and the script trying to define `retrieve` won't error so `retrieve` will be defined.

---

Aside: Your save function won't work for [a different reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute). Use `addEventListener`, not `onclick` attributes.