# Problem viewing a div with a simple function

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a problem I would say stupid with html and javascript, a simple function that should make me visible and invisible a div crashes the html making it empty!

```
<button onclick="open()">Modifica</button>
```

js:

```
var x = document.getElementById ("joseph");
   if (x.hidden == false) {
     x.hidden = true;
   } else {
     x.hidden = false;
}
```

**before:**
[image]

**after:**
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Where's the element with the ID of `joseph`? Why do you have a space in `getElementById ("joseph");`?

Comment: Where's the *function*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write pre-defined methods. It works same for all other tech stacks such as Mysql, PHP, etc.

Recommend using **opens**, not **open** if you insist to use the open word.

```
<button onclick="opens()">Modifica</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hit a variation of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute).

When searching for a variable named `open` the browser finds `document.open` before it finds your `open` function.

[`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open) opens a new document for writing (with `document.write`) which erases the existing document.

[`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) is also predefined, so making a new global function with that name is not advised.

As with the linked question: Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onclick` attributes.