# Want to stop my page from refreshing when submitting a form(onsubmit ="return false" not working)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using javascript and html, here is my code, not exact code, the form body is pretty big so
I am not sharing it:

**Problems I'm facing:**

1. Page refreshes when I submit the form.
2. I have 2 forms in my page and "return false" works on the 1st from but not on the 2nd.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="col_8 signin" id="s1">
            <form name="sigin" onsubmit="login(); return false" method="post">
            //FORM CONTENT//    
            </form>
       </div>

        <div class="col_8 signup" id="s2">
            <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
            <form name="sigup" onsubmit="submit(); return false" method="post">
            //FORM CONTENT//  
            </form>
       </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Comment: Bottom line: don't use `onxxxxx` attributes with all its pitfalls, use event listeners instead.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a form's `submit` method will submit the form while bypassing event listeners.

So with this code:

> ```
> onsubmit="submit(); return false"
> ```

1. Something triggers a normal form submission
2. The event handler triggers an unblockable form submission
3. `return false` cancels the submission at *1*
4. The submission from *2* goes ahead

---

It is possible you are *trying* to call a *different* function called `submit` and are hitting the form's `submit` method by accident [because intrinsic event attributes are awful and screw up scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute).

Comment: yes im trying to call a function that i am using to validate the form values entered by the user, is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: @MohdAfsal — The answer to the linked question explains how to deal with that.

Comment: So basically just use event listeners?