# How do I add ontouch event after onclick on same HTML span tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, bootstrap-4

I added a span tag to wrap icon button (icon ion-md-chatbubbles) in my html page, and I added onclick event listener on the same tag

```
         ...
            <span onclick="(function($){
                $('.nav-tabs a[href=&quot;#tab-manga-discussion&quot;]').tab('show')
            })(jQuery);"
            >
            <a href="#manga-discussion"><i class="icon ion-md-chatbubbles"></i></a>
            </span> 
         ...
```

In desktop it works fine, however I also need to add a touch event listener in that span tag because in mobile devices an user has to touch twice in the icon button to navigate to nav-tab anchor element (**#tab-manga-discussion**). I tried to add ontouch event after onclick in the tag but didn't work

```
ontouchstart="(function($){
                    $('.nav-tabs a[href=&quot;#tab-manga-discussion&quot;]').tab('show')
                })(jQuery);"
```

In the end I would have the two events combined on same span tag

```
         ...
            <span onclick="(function($){
                $('.nav-tabs a[href=&quot;#tab-manga-discussion&quot;]').tab('show')
            })(jQuery);"
                ontouchstart="(function($){
                $('.nav-tabs a[href=&quot;#tab-manga-discussion&quot;]').tab('show')
            })(jQuery);"
            >
         ...
```

**Edit**:

I replaced the codes above in favor of inline-js script and addEventListener() method

```js
...
                <span id="action_icon_wrapper">
                <a href="#manga-discussion"><i class="icon ion-md-chatbubbles"></i></a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        if(!is_touch_enabled())
                        document.getElementById("action_icon_wrapper").addEventListener("click", nav_icon_button);

                        if(is_touch_enabled())
                            document.getElementById("action_icon_wrapper").addEventListener("touchstart", nav_icon_button, false);

                        function nav_icon_button(){
                            (function($){
                            $(".nav-tabs a[href='#tab-manga-discussion']").tab('show')
                            })(jQuery);
                        }

                        function is_touch_enabled() {
                            return ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) ||
                            ( navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ) ||
                            ( navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0 );
                        }
                    </script>
                </span>
...
```

The script works fine in desktop, but strangely on mobile devices the user needs to tap for the second time to go to discussion tab-pane section. If that happens as long as the page isn't refreshed (reloaded) works fine.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Intrinsic event attributes, like `onclick` are awful. They have [weird scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute) and are a form of [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). Best practice is to use the [`addEventListener` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

The [`touchstart` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event) **does not** have an associated intrinsic event [attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#attributes-3). Use `addEventListener` instead.