# reset() function within an in statement is executing regardless of the condition?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, dom

I have this form in HTML with the onclick connected to this function in Javascript that is supposed to only clear the form if the input is "Yes", or else display `<p1>` that is hidden by default using css.

```js
function clear() {
  if (document.getElementById("reset").textContent == "Yes") {
    document.getElementById("main").reset()
    return
  }
  const err = document.getElementById("error");
  err.style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<form id="main">
  <p1>
    <p1 id="introduction"></p1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p1 id="annualGoals"></p1><br>
    <p1 id="monthlyBudget"></p1>
  </p1>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <div id="finish">
    Reset (Yes/No)?<br>
    <input type="text" id="reset"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="clear()"><br><br>
    <p1 id="error">We're unable to complete your request, please refresh the page to try again.</p1>
  </div>
```

Currently, the function is resetting the form no matter the input. I've tried toying around with the function if statement by adding an else condition in case the input is "No" but even if there's no input, it resets the form. I'm very new to Javascript so there must be something I'm not seeing in the logic.

Comment: Your button is a "submit" button, so it's going to submit the form and reload the page.

Comment: [Functions named `clear` and `onclick` attributes are an **awful** mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613748/why-cant-i-call-a-function-named-clear-from-an-onclick-attribute).

Comment: Try `onclick="clear();return false;"` to cancel the form submit

Comment: Learning to debug / see what's happening is a valuable step:  In this case, open browser, press F12 to see the debugging console, select Network tab, load your page - you should see various requests (possibly just one if you don't have images etc).   When it's calmed down, click the clear button.   Then interact with your form - when you click the `submit` button, you'll see another network request.  This is the "submit and reload" mentioned above - it's the same as press F5 to reload the page.

Comment: @Pointy @Quentin Thank you! I've changed the input type to button and changed the function to resetPage(). I think my function is still having trouble with the 

`document.getElementById("reset").textContent == "Yes"`

condition sadly and is instead skipping to the code outside of the if statement even if I input "Yes". Could I ask for help on this as well? I'd like to use a user input instead of getting rid of the input and just using a submit button.

Comment: Is there some reason you are reinventing the wheel and not just using `<input type="reset">`? Also `<p1>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The code is part of an assignment where I have to take a user input from the actual web page and I don't think buttons count so I want the user to type something to reset the page. Thank you for the feedback on `<p1>`, changed to `<p>`!

Comment: The content of an `<input>` is accessed by the `.value` property, not `.textContent`.

Comment: You are also not using `<p>` and `<br>` elements correctly. You can't nest a paragraph within another paragraph and line breaks should not be used for page layout, they are only for pushing a portion of a block to its own line. Use CSS for layout spacing.

Comment: Additionally, you should be declaring variables that reference your elements outside of your function so that you don't wind up scanning the DOM to recreate the references every time the function executes.