# How to change a value when i onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a drop down list like this:

```
<select name="store-cost" class="target">
    <option value = '100'>100</option>
    <option value = '500'>500</option>
    <option value = '1500'>1500</option>
</select>
```

and jquery to see what the user has chosen

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    console.log($( this ).val());
});
```

and i have a button that calls jquery function:

```
<a href="#" onclick = donateNow(100)>Donate</a>
```

How do I change the value in the function donateNow according to the user's option?

Many thanks

EDIT, sorry didn't make myself clear, I would like to change I would like to change the function donateNow() param according to the user's chosen option

Comment: @felix he did not mean to change the value of select element.. he wants to change the parameter of `donateNow` function according the the select element's value...!

Comment: You can get it inside `function donatenow()` by `$( ".target" ).val()`

Comment: @Rajaprabhu: Ah... that makes sense as well.

Comment: @FelixKling The OP is not asking how to change the selected value.  They are asking how to retrieve it to put into a different function.  Yes the question is a duplicate but it isn't THAT duplicate :)

Comment: Put simply, you don't pass any argument to `donateNow` and retrieve the value inside the function instead. Or if you really want to make the function accept an argument, pass the value to the function. You already know how to *get* the value.

Comment: Please be aware of the [nasty pitfalls with inline event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty:

```
<a href="#" onclick="donateNow($('.target').val())">Donate</a>
```

The better practice:

```
<a href="#" onclick="donateNow()">Donate</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function donateNow() {
  var amount = $('.target').val();
  //use amount
}
</script>
```

Comment: what's this..? how would a script works outside of a script tag..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Why would `donateNow(100)` work at all? This is exactly the way to go!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: The onclick value accepts arbitrary JS.

Comment: I'd suggest to put the attribute value inside `"` quotes. The `'` should not make any troubles, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Scorpion yeah that's true, link given by felix clearly states that.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qhza6/)**

Try this,

Update : a better way.

You can get the value in the function definition.

```
<a href="#" >Donate</a>

$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    console.log($( this ).val());
});

$("a:contains('Donate')").click(function(){
     donateNow($( ".target" ).val()):
});
function donateNow(selectedVal){
    console.log(selectedVal);
}
```

Comment: Do you alter every function definition if you want to use the function with different values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
<select name="store-cost" class="target">
    <option value = '100'>100</option>
    <option value = '500'>500</option>
    <option value = '1500'>1500</option>
</select>
<a href="#" onclick = "donateNow($('.target').val())">Donate</a>
```

And in your javascript:

```
function donateNow(currValue)
{
    alert('you donated: '+ currValue);
}
```

Here you can check it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7ykA/):