# Button is removed from html page after executing function which name is remove()

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why this piece of code will remove the buton after click in FF and Chrome? IE will show an alert.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function remove()
{
alert('test');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="remove();" value="Remove"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't name functions after JavaScript methods or events.

Comment: [Don't use inline event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196) or at least know what you are doing. [DOM nodes have a `remove` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) and that's what is getting called, not your function.

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks. I knew there was a question just like this in here somewhere from seeing it before. Finding it took a little work, but my OCD feels better now.

Answer (score 1):

Because javascript has a remove method. Name your function abcd and it is fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function abcd()
{
alert('test');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="abcd();" value="Remove"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "remove" is not listed as event here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events. Do you have any reference?

Comment: I was looking too. I only saw this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove

Comment: sorry, my bad, I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use inline event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196) or at least know what you are doing.

The problem is that the properties of the element itself are in the scope of the inline event handler, and [DOM nodes have a `remove` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) *****. So `remove()` is equivalent to `this.remove()`, i.e. it calls the `remove` method of the button.

**Solutions:**

- Rename your function
- [Use a different way](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) [to bind event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

---

*: This is a relatively new API which is not supported by IE yet, so it works fine in IE.

Answer (score 0):

using inline event handlers is usually considered bad practice, as you are asking the browser to parse javascript events from html strings, a much better way would be as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    window.myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
    window.myButton.addEventListener("click",myButtonFunction);
  });

  function myButtonFunction()
  {
    alert('test');    
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Remove"/>
</body>
</html>
```

also you don't need to declare it as a window variable (global), unless you want to access it in your function. (but could also access it again via document.getElementById("myButton")