# Function won't call

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have a function that is to be executed on click of a button. It is not working when I click the button. All of my other functions work when I click the button.

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("test");
    test.onclick = function() {
        var summonerid = document.getElementById("username").value.length;
        function summonerName() {
            if(summonerid = 4){
                alert("Come on");
            }
            else {
                alert("wai");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="summoner" id="username" maxlength="16" autocomplete="off" style="font-size: 22pt; font-family: times new roman">
<input type="submit" id="test" style="font-size: 22pt; font-family: times new roman">
```

Comment: If you mean `summonerName()` doesn't run then it's because it's never called.

Comment: You have `if set variable to 4`, when you mean `if variable is equal to`. One vs. two equal signs.

Comment: I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript Guide about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 1):

Line by line corrections:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("test");
    // Typo!
    button.onclick = function() {
        var summonerid = document.getElementById("username").value.length;
        // This was never called
        function summonerName(id) {
            // this assigned 4 to summonerid 
            if(id === 4){
                alert("Come on");
            }
            else {
                alert("wai");
            }
        }
        summonerName(summonerid);
    };

};
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `summonerName(summonerid);` be _inside_ the onclick listener? (Please clean indents)

Comment: You´re correct, I was writing in the browser and got lost in indentation...

Comment: By the way, `test.onclick` worked, since the element has id `test` so it's accessible with that name in the global scope. So it's more a bad practice than a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You could simplify your code a bit like this

HTML :

```
 <input type="button" id="test" value="Submit" onclick="summonerName()"/>
```

JS :

```
function summonerName()
{
  var summonerid = document.getElementById("username").value.length;
  if(summonerid==4)
  {
    //Do what needs to be done
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Inline javascript is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Please note that there actual [practical disadvantages of using inline event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196).