# Changing value of a span using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html with a span like this:

`<span class="className">0</span>` and it should display: `0`

The problem is, how could I add a value (e.g. when value is 2, it will become 3) to the span by clicking a button and by doing it using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the content of any [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) using:

- [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

look at this snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var button = document.querySelector("#mybutton");
   var span = document.querySelector(".className");
  
   button.onclick = function() {
     span.textContent= parseInt(span.textContent, 10) + 1;
   }
  
});
```

```html
<span class="className">0</span>
<button id="mybutton">add</button>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to use `onclick=""` which [I don't recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/4343318), you could do something like this:

```js
var myFunction = function() {
   var span = document.querySelector(".className");  
   span.textContent= parseInt(span.textContent, 10) + 1;  
}
```

```html
<span class="className">0</span>
<button id="mybutton" onclick="myFunction()">add</button>
```

Comment: It isn't working for me.  The span value was still 0.

Comment: How if, I am assigning an `onclick=""` to the button?

Comment: for that you need to declare a named function in your global namespace, and call it inside the button's onclick attribute, look at the edited answer