# How to change div id dynamically

Tags: javascript

Maybe you can help me with this:

I have a function that ads a div by a button click.
Any div contains a checkbox and a text field.
If the checkbox is checked the text field is green, if not, the text field is red.

I don't know how to assign a dynamic div name for the "procedure" div, as the counter, like id = procedure1, id=procedure2... and then access the background color as procedure1.style.backgroundColor...

Thank you!

```
var counter = 1;

function addInput(divName) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id='check' onclick='if(this.checked){procedure.style.backgroundColor=`green`;}
          else {procedure.style.backgroundColor=`red`;}'><input type='text' id='procedure'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: ...id='procedure'" + counter + ">";

Comment: Unvalid quote `\`` with `\`green\``.

Comment: @Matt R  good idea, but is: id='procedura" + counter + "'>";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using IDs for this at all. **Traverse** the DOM instead to find the corresponding `<input>`. In your specific case, the [*next sibling*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) of the checkbox is the element you want to manipulate:

```
onclick='this.nextSibling.style.backgroundColor = this.checked ? "green" : "red";'
```

I also suggest to learn about [other ways of binding event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html), because inline event handlers [have many disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/218196) and using `innerHTML` like this makes your code more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the elements with `document.createElement` rather than with a string, then you can use `setAttribute`.

```
var dynamicId = 'someId';
element.setAttribute('id', dynamicId);
```

So for your example

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
input.setAttribute('id', 'check');
input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

However, you might have noticed that using this approach you don't even need to use IDs. You can simply keep a reference to the elements you created with some variables.

```
var procedure1 = document.createElement('input');
var procedure2 = document.createElement('input');

procedure1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // do something with procedure2
  procedure2.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to do this

to set: `$('#myObj').attr('id','NEWID');`

or `$('#myObj').prop('id','NEWID');`

to get :   `$('#myObj').attr('id');`

Comment: From the JavaScript tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*