# JavaScript function called "action"

Tags: javascript, function, types

Can someone explain me why a function called "action" creates a type error in the following code as soon as the button is surrounded by the form tags. I assume this leads to a strange conflict with the form's action attribute, but i wonder why it happens in this scope ("action" is not defined in any other way):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function action() {
            alert('test');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="click" onClick="action();">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _I am surprised there is no duplicate for this question_

Comment: That's the way inline event handlers work. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler/21975639#21975639

Comment: @Rayon: this has been asked before, but I can imagine that it is difficult to name the question or what to look for without knowing what the issue is. I mean, the title of this question is not very indicative of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the form, `action` is a string reference to the form action. If you change your onclick to `alert(action)` you will get the action of the form (which will be an empty string for your specific form).

In the same manner, `form` will be a reference to a form, and `method` will contain the form method, if you use them within the form. `window.action` will still refer to your function.

Comment: @Rayon: Really? [Not in chrome, in my experiments](https://jsfiddle.net/hgczsppr/)

Comment: Ooh.. You are right! I did not change `Load Type` in Fiddle :(

Comment: Stupid me did not see that the call is the problem, not the function itself. Now everything makes sense again.