# Pattern for asking Javascript to pay attention to multiple element events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm writing a Javascript library to monitor how the user interacts with form fields. It will have to monitor multiple events for a given element, so I can't use an onblah handler.

I would like the HTML author to decide what fields are monitored. I thought I'd offer something like this:

```
<script src="formWatch.js"></script>

<form ...>
    <textarea name="blah" onload="watch(this)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then `watch()` would register various event handlers on the element. But it seems `onload` only fires on elements which load resources?

What is a good pattern for allowing the HTML author to decide what elements a Javascript library will pay attention to?

Comment: You can assign the same handler to multipe events, i.e. both an onblah and an onblubb property. And of course you shouldn't be using inline handlers anyway.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but that won't work for this application. It's a lot of redundancy for the user, and it hard codes which events are being watched; that is decided by the library and may change. Could you explain what the problem is with inline handlers and what the preferred alternative is?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

You have many options. Maybe try going with a [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) tag:

```
<textarea name="blah" data-monitored="true">
```

and in your JS you collect all these elements using a method like so:

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("[data-monitored='true']");
```

Comment: Interesting! What's the advantage over assigning it to the "monitored" class?

Comment: @Schwern There isn't really any advantage, it just helps to, in your mind, separate javascript data from styling rules.

Answer (score 0):

What's about using `onfocus` event handler and fire `focus` event on first load? Then you will manage multiply events inside this handler as you did with your `watch` function.