# How do I style a table so that specific boxes in the table change colors onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make the elements in this table change color from the background color to red and back to the default color when I click them?

```
<table align="center" style="height: 355px;" width="664" border="3px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 94px;">25</td>
      <td style="width: 94px;">26</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">27</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">28</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">29</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">30</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick listener to the elements you want (I'm presuming that you are generating the cells dynamically)

```
<table align="center" style="height: 355px;" width="664" border="3px">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 94px;" onclick="changeColor(this)">25</td>
          <td style="width: 94px;">26</td>
          <td style="width: 95px;">27</td>
          <td style="width: 95px;">28</td>
          <td style="width: 95px;">29</td>
          <td style="width: 95px;">30</td>
          <td style="width: 95px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

and in jquery you would do something like this (alternatively use javascript):

```
function changeColor(elt){
  $elt = $(elt);
  $elt.toggleClass("redBg");
}
```

In css:

```
.redBg{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: [onclick vs event-handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler)

Answer (score 0):

you can play with the classes, by appending and removing them as you want. Also you can change more style by this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table tbody tr td').on('click', changeColor);
});

function changeColor() {
 if(!this.classList.contains('first')){
  this.classList.add('first');
  this.classList.remove('second');
 } else {
 this.classList.remove('first');
 this.classList.add('second');
 }
}
```

```css
.first{
  background : red;
}
.second{
  background : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" class="table" style="height: 355px;" width="664" border="3px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 94px;">25</td>
      <td style="width: 94px;">26</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">27</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">28</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">29</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">30</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this will work on all boxes, OP asked for specific boxes, plus you could just use the toggleClass property instead of going into conditions

Comment: that's true, i just tried to keep the code as simple as i can. so he can understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use with [`classList.toggle('class')`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjN7siVyfnTAhXCsY8KHeN-DMMQFgg1MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FElement%2FclassList&usg=AFQjCNHl5HGg38jFQ1TEZv6ZBdarl_G85w)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr td').forEach(function(a){
a.addEventListener('click',function(){
this.classList.toggle('color')
})
})
```

```css
.color{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" style="height: 355px;" width="664" border="3px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 94px;">25</td>
      <td style="width: 94px;">26</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">27</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">28</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">29</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">30</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put something like `data-color=true` and then just assign them the color change

```js
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    len = td.length,
    i;
function changeColor(){
  var color = this.style.background!="red";
  this.style.background = (color?"red":"initial");
}
for(i=0;i<len;i+=1){
  if(td[i].getAttribute("data-color")=="true"){
    td[i].onclick = changeColor;
  }
}
```

```html
<table align="center" style="height: 355px;" width="664" border="3px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 94px;" data-color="true">25</td>
      <td style="width: 94px;" data-color="true">26</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">27</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;" data-color="true">28</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">29</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;" data-color="true">30</td>
      <td style="width: 95px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this will work on all boxes, OP asked for specific boxes.