# Keep 2 <select> in sync when value changes

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have two `<select>`s with the same `<option>`s.

If a user selects a value in the first one, the value on the second one should change as well to keep both in sync.

This is what I tried so far:

```js
function data_copy() {
  if (document.form1.copy[0].checked) {
    for (i = document.form1.state.options.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (document.form1.state.options[i].selected)
        document.form1.state2.options[i].selected = true;
    }
  } else {
    document.form1.state2.options[0].selected = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080" alink="#ff0000">
  <table width='400' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0'>
    <form name=form1 method=post action='http://www.plus2net.com'>

      <tr><td >State</td><td>
        <SELECT NAME="state" onchange="data_copy()">
          <Option value="One">One</option>
          <Option value="Two">Two</option>
          <Option value="Three">Three</option>
          <Option value="Four">Four</option>
        </SELECT>
      </td></tr>

      <tr><td >
      <tr><td >State</td><td>
        <SELECT NAME="state2" >
          <Option value="One">One</option>
          <Option value="Two">Two</option>
          <Option value="Three">Three</option>
          <Option value="Four">Four</option>
        </SELECT>
      </td></tr>

      <tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type=submit value=Submit>
    </form></td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just get a reference to both `<select>` using [`document.getElemebtById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`document.querySelector(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or any other `document.getElement...()` function and, once the first one changes, assign its value to the second one:

```
const state1 = document.getElementById('state1');
const state2 = document.getElementById('state2');

state1.onchange = function(e) {
    state2.value = e.target.value;
};
```

Also, there are multiple issues with your code:

- A `<form>` is not allowed inside a `<table>`, so you either wrap the whole table with it or put it in a single cell. Inside a [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) element you can only use `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tbody>` and `<tr>`.
- Unquoted `HTML` attributes are also valid but, if they contain untrusted data, it will be more difficult to escape them to avoid XSS attacks. Actually, most `HTML` escaping tools will assume the usage of quotes. Anyway, you should also be consistent with that, so either use double, single or no quotes at all.
- You should use lowercase for your `HTML` code. While browsers will still understand uppercase, it is a convention to use lowercase due to its better readability. This comes from the old [`xHTML`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) which required lowercase.
- You should also avoid using event attributes in order to keep your presentation and your logic separated and also due to the way the scope for inline elements is resolved.

  There's a good explanation on that in this other answer: [onclick="" vs event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler#answer-21975639)
- You should not use `HTML` attributes to style your elements. That's `CSS` concern.

  Actually, [`bgcolor`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_bgcolor.asp), [`text`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_text.asp), [`link`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_link.asp)... Are all unsupported in `HTML5`.
- Lastly, if you are using the `<table>` element just for layout, without any semantic meaning, then you should use other elements instead, maybe `<ul>` and `<li>` or just `<div>`, and position them using `CSS`.

  Maybe [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can come in handy, although `position`, `float` and `display` should be more than enough for your use case.

All together, it should look like this:

```js
const state1 = document.getElementById('state1');
const state2 = document.getElementById('state2');

state1.onchange = function(e) {
  state2.value = e.target.value;
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  width: 400px;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: .25rem;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
}

.legend {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .75rem;
  margin: 1rem 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  transition: box-shadow ease-in .125s;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<form
  name="form"
  method="post"
  action="http://www.plus2net.com">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="legend">State</td>
      <td>
        <select name="state" id="state1">
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
          <option value="Four">Four</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td class="legend">State</td>
      <td>
        <select name="state2" id="state2">
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
        </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
   
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="button">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[name='state']").on("change",function(){
    $("select[name='state2']").val($("select[name='state']").val());
}
```

This will change the second select to the value of the first select when the first has its value changed

Comment: This is jquery..., so Will need to add the jquery library. Will test and let you know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SukhpreetSinghAlang Well you did tag your question with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

One for all, pure vanillaJS

```js
function data_copy(n)
{
  document.querySelectorAll('[NAME^="state"]').forEach(el=>el.value = document.form1['state'+n].value)
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>


<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080" alink="#ff0000">
<table width='400' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0'>
<form name=form1 method=post action='http://www.plus2net.com'>


<tr><td >State</td><td><SELECT NAME="state1" onchange="data_copy(1)">
<Option value="One">One</option>
<Option value="Two">Two</option>
<Option value="Three">Three</option>
<Option value="Four">Four</option>

</SELECT>
</td></tr>


<tr><td >State</td><td><SELECT NAME="state2" onchange="data_copy(2)">
<Option value="One">One</option>
<Option value="Two">Two</option>
<Option value="Three">Three</option>
<Option value="Four">Four</option>

</SELECT>
</td></tr>


<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type=submit value=Submit></td></tr> </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because it's es6, if you need to support older browsers you can transpile it in BABEL, like [THIS](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=true&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=function%20data_copy(n)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20document.querySelectorAll('%5BNAME%5E%3D%22state%22%5D').forEach(el%3D%3Eel.value%20%3D%20document.form1%5B'state'%2Bn%5D.value)%0D%0A%7D)