# Passing onclick event in template literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to pass url through onclick event, its not working.
 there is `<body onload="displayBookmarks()">` to initialise displayBookmarks function as soon as the page gets loaded

```
function deleteBookmark(url){
    alert(url);
};

function displayBookmarks(){
    bookmarksResults.innerHTML = "";
    for (let a in bookmarks){
        let name = bookmarks[a].name;
        let url =  bookmarks[a].url;
        bookmarksResults.innerHTML += `<div class="well"> <h3> ${name} <a class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" href=${url} >Visit</a>  <a onclick=${deleteBookmark(url)} class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</a></h3></div>`
    }
}
```

The main problem is `onclick=${deleteBookmark(url)}` 
**As soon as the page loads it starts displaying the url but I want to to be shown only when delete button is pressed.**

Comment: Simple: Don't use html strings and [inline event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572). Template literals are not your real problem.

Comment: Why are you using an interpolation for the value of the event handler attribute? You indeed don't want to call the function when constructing the string. You want a literal `onclick="deleteBookmark(url)"` to appear in the HTML.

Comment: `... ${deleteBookmark(url)} ... ` is immediately evaluated when the template literal is defined. Since `deleteBookmark(url)` is a function invocation expression, this is the cause of your problem. The `${...}` inside backticks _evaluates_ Javascript code.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that there is another way to do this with encapsulation. I don't know if I would recommend doing it like this at all but since you've asked the question.

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");

const button = ((app) => {
  
  let _url;
  
 const _log = (data) => {
   console.log(data);
  }
  
  let _content = `<button onclick="(${_log})('${_url}')">test</button>`;
  
  const _setContent = () => {
   _content = `<button onclick="(${_log})('${_url}')">test</button>`;
  }
  
  const _setUrl = (url) => {
   _url = url;
  }
  
  return {
   setUrl: (url) => {
     _setUrl(url);
      _setContent();
    },
   render: () => {
     app.innerHTML = _content;
    }
  }
})(app)

const url =  'www.something.com';
button.setUrl(url);
button.render();
```

```html
<section id="app">...</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const markUp = `
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
`;

document.body.innerHTML = markUp;

window.myFunction = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked');
};
```