# How can I run jQuery script before form submit without using OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.Net WebForms application where I am using jQuery validation. There are several buttons to submit the form, each with different options on the back end.

I have a custom `validateForm()` function that I can assign to the `OnClientClick` event of all the buttons, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution where I don't have to specifically give each button the `OnClientClick` property.

So basically, **is it possible to capture the $(form).submit() event before an asp button is submitted? Without using the OnClientClick attribute?**

---

**Solved**: My issue was actually not because I couldn't catch the submit, but because the buttons were `<a>` links instead of inputs. I didn't realize this and made the post while at home trying to fix it from memory.

Any of the below solutions should work in the scenario above with actual submit buttons

Comment: what ryan said. or you could attach 'click' listeners to individual buttons. `.on('click', ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach a listener to the `submit` event:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    // Do whatever you need to do here ...
    // You could also do `event.preventDefault();`,
    // if you wanted to stop the submit.
});
```

Comment: Last time I tried that it didn't work. I will try again tomorrow to be certain

Comment: @MickelsonMichael, is your code wrapped in `$(document).on('ready'`?

Comment: see my updated post. Turns out I was just forgetful and actually had a completely different problem. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `onsubmit` event that will execute a JavaScript when a form is submitted from any button.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return ValidationFunction();">
```

And your JS function should return `true` or `false` as

```
function ValidationFunction() {
    // Your jQuery validation
    if (isValide) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Another option using JQuery to attaches an event handler to form submission

```
$(document).ready(function () { // << to make sure DOM is loaded
    $('#form1').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // << the default action of the event will not be triggered
        var isValide = false;

        if (isValide) {
            alert('ok');
            this.submit();
        }
        else {
            alert('Not Valid');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It is considered a best practice to attach the event listener using JavaScript rather than an HTML attribute.

Comment: In this particular case I don't want to attach the function to the `form` itself

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen please share a reference

Comment: @MickelsonMichael Check updated answer for another solution

Comment: @WaelAbbas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler
https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3ymzdu/onclick_vs_getelementbyidclick_vs_event_listener/
It is all about separation of concerns.