# Javascript :: Use Variable as String for Object ID and Properties;

Tags: javascript, string, variables, properties, objectid

```
function ftest (P1, P2) {
"use strict";

  document.getElementById(String(P1)).display = String(P2);
}
```

document.getElementById(**String(P1)**)
use the parameter P1 as the ObjectID;

display = **String(P2)**
use parameter P2 as the ObjectStyle Property;

this way manner to avoid clutter when passing values at the workflow::

```
onclick="ftest(objectname,objectproperty)"
```

instead of

> onclick="ftest('objectname','objectproperty')"

the result would be
Object is Null or Unknown Property ?
when trying to make things clean at the html code;

Comment: No, putting `String()` around `P2` does not change the `objectname` variable that is supplied as an argument to become a `"objectname"` string literal.

Comment: If you are looking for clean html code, just [don't use `onclick` attributes at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

You cant. The only way to do this would be:

```
 var objectname = "objectname";
```

then

```
 ftest(objectname)
```

would work. however if your aim is

> to make things clean at the html code

then remove the inline eventlisteners and do something like:

```
 // html
 <button id="ftest" > ftest </ button>

 // js
 const on = (selector, event, handler) => document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(event, handler);

 on("#ftest", "click", () => ftest("objectname", "objectproperty"));
```

Comment: understood, it is not because the onclick is typed as html string that the javascript parameters are identified as such; would have to specify it like that;

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but **objectproperty** should be defined.

Something like that:

Somewehre in the script (quick and dirty solution):

```
window.objectproperty = "none";
```

call:

```
onclick="ftest(objectId, objectproperty)"
```

ftest:

```
function ftest (P1, P2) {
  "use strict";
  P1.style.display = P2;
}
```

Comment: understood, it is not because the onclick is typed as html string that the javascript parameters are identified as such; would have to specify it like that;

Answer (score 0):

You must create object then pass it to function.

look at this example :

```js
function ftest (obj) {
"use strict";
  document.getElementById(obj.P1).style.display = obj.P2;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='test'>I Am Block</h1>
<script>
var obj = {
 P1 : 'test',
 P2 : 'inline'
}
</script>
<button onclick="ftest(obj)">Test Me</button>
```