# ES6 Javascript Class and function scopes

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple js tab in new ES6 code but i am a bit troubles with scope of variables and exporting class.

Here is my code

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../css/_style.scss';
import './mediaupload.js';
//
let i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
class SMDVadmin{
    openTab(evt, tabname){
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(tabname).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
}
export default SMDVadmin;
```

and i am using the function `openTab` as

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" onClick="openTab(e, tab1)" id="th1">HOme</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" onClick="openTab(e, tab2)" id="th2">Address</a></li>
</ul>
```

But on clicking there is an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: openTab is not defined`

BUT, if i code like this,its working :) :

```
let i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

const openTab = (evt, tabname) => {
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabname).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

window.openTab = openTab;
```

But i have more other functions and I want them to keep in a class to maintain a integrity

Comment: SMDVadmin.openTab() ?

Comment: No, you don't want to use `class` if you don't want to construct instances. To keep them maintainable, putting them all in the same module (or object) is enough.

Comment: First of all, stop declaring that `i` variable as a global. Declare it as local inside that function!

Comment: [Don't use inline `onclick` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572). Also the `tab1` and `tab2` that you want to pass to the function should be string literals.

Answer (score -1):

You've effectively "namespaced" your `openTab` method by putting it in a class. You must create an instance of the class and then call the method on that instance.

```
var smdvAdmin = new SMDVadmin()

smdvAdmin.openTab()
```

Alternatively, you could make the method a static, thus not requiring a new instance:

```
class SMDVadmin{
    static openTab(evt, tabname){}
}

SMDVadmin.openTab()
```

You may not need the class at all if you are importing a single method from a file.

You could instead just export the method

```
const openTab = (evt, tabname) => {}

export default openTab;
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This properly addresses the OP's misunderstanding

Comment: I downvoted before you added "*You may not need the class at all …*" (which is the proper solution), but unfortunately the edit was during the grace period and my vote is now locked.

Comment: I would disagree that it is the "proper" solution. The OP states: "I have more other functions and I want them to keep in a class" – so explaining to them how they can use their method from the class is not worth a downvote.

Comment: No, but keeping plain functions (that are no instance methods) in a `class` is wrong.