# Pass varible in javascript function from loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

It is necessary to pass a variable to the function in a loop. When you click on the button, the id (or object) should fall into the function.

```
 $.each(data, function (index,subcatObj) {
                        if(subcatObj.didOrganizer==0){
                            y.innerHTML="<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"return makeDid(subcatObj);\" value=\"Назначить куратором1\">"
                        }
                        else {
                            y.innerHTML="<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"return deleteDid(subcatObj);\" value=\"Снять куратора\">"
                        }  


            function makeDid(item) {
                console.log(item)
            }
            function deleteDid(item) {
                console.log(item)
            }      
              })
```

But an error occurs:

> subcatObj is not defined

How to fix it?

Comment: do a `console.log (data)` before the loop and see what the contents is of `data`. Your clue is in there.

Comment: Since you're working with jQuery, do not use `innerHTML`! And [never use inline event listener attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572).

Comment: if(subcatObj.didOrganizer==0){
                       // y.innerHTML = subcatObj.didOrganizer;
                        console.log(subcatObj);
                        y.innerHTML="<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"return makeDid(subcatObj);\" value=\"Назначить куратором1\">"
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `input` element explicitly (and not just in an HTML string), and then use `addEventListener` on it (or assign to its `onclick` property) so as to capture `subcatObj` in a closure, so the variable can be used in the handler:

```
function makeDid(item) {
  console.log(item)
}
function deleteDid(item) {
  console.log(item)
}

$.each(data, function(index, subcatObj) {
  // next line not needed if y is empty already:
  y.innerHTML = '';
  const input = y.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
  input.type = 'button';
  // best to use strict equality if possible:
  if (subcatObj.didOrganizer === 0) {
    input.value = 'Назначить куратором1';
    input.addEventListener('click', () => makeDid(subcatObj));
  } else {
    input.value = 'Снять куратора';
    input.addEventListener('click', () => deleteDid(subcatObj));
  }
});
```

(onclick *attributes* in the HTML are often difficult to manage and are generally considered to be pretty poor practice anyway)

Comment: Thanks for the help!