# Passing object as a parameter in a template literal in javascript

Tags: javascript

I currently have an object which I want to pass as a parameter to another function inside a template literal:

```
    var template = `<button onclick="onclick(${object})"></button>`;
```

However, this makes the parameter become a string value: `[object Object]` and doesn't pass the parameter. Is there any way to pass this parameter into the function?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There is no function inside that template literal, it's just a string, and your object is string-interpolated as well. Don't use `onclick` event handler attributes, install the event listener function properly!

Comment: That you don't need to deal with object serialisation and deserialisation, not with js escaping, not with html escaping, not with the weird scopes of attribute event handlers, that you actually get to use the real object (same identity), and that it is more efficient. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572

Answer (score 7):

You are going to need to represent your object as a string. You can do this using `JSON.stringify`:

```
var template = `<button onclick="handleClick(${JSON.stringify(obj).split('"').join("&quot;")})"></button>`;
```

You will need to escape double quotes (which this code does), as well as potentially HTML entities and single quotes if used for your onclick event (this code doesn't do that).

onclick="onclick" actually calls window.onclick - meaning that it picks up clicks anywhere. You should use a different name (such as handleClick).

I would suggest refraining from using inline event listeners due to the high risk of cross-site-scripting security issues, as well as the need to escape certain data.

Comment: and how would I be able to turn it back into an object?

Comment: Javascript should evaluate the stringified code as an object. JSON is a stricter form of Javascript object literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax

Comment: However if you need to convert a JSON string to an object, you can run ```JSON.parse(string)```

Comment: Your warning misses the point. It still fails for `{example: "apostrophe: ' "}`. What you actually need to do is html-entity-escape the string after serialising the object.

Answer (score -2):

```
var template =`<button onclick="handleClick(${JSON.stringify(object)})"></button>`;
```

When you want to pass an object without it being automatically converted to a string when using template literals with ${}, you can handle the click event separately and pass the object as a parameter.

In this example, the handleClick function is defined to take an object as a parameter. The JSON.stringify function is used to convert the object to a JSON string when passing it as a parameter in the inline event handler. Inside the handleClick function, you can then parse the JSON string back to an object if needed.

Comment: Don't forget to also html-escape the value when putting it in a html attribute