# One button runs a function, a second button runs a different function but only if the 1st function gets run

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, conditional-statements

I have 4 **buttons** assigned to run 4 different `functions`.  Seen below

```
document.getElementById("buttonOne").addEventListener("click", functionOne);
document.getElementById("buttonTwo").addEventListener("click", functionTwo);
document.getElementById("buttonThree").addEventListener("click", functionThree);
document.getElementById("buttonFour").addEventListener("click", functionFour);
```

I have another function,`functionFive`, that is not controlled by any button.

All of these functions set parameters on a 3D object when the given button is clicked. Clicking **button one** runs `functionOne`, setting a specific set of parameters.  If those parameters are set from `functionOne` and I click **button four**, I want `functionFive` to be run.

If those parameters from `functionOne` are not set when **button four** is clicked, I want `functionFour` to run.

To clarify, I only want this `functionFive` to run if `functionOne`has already run and its parameters are set.

Can someone help me write this script? 
I've rewritten my question to fit my exact need. My original description was condensed to try and simplify it so it wouldn't be this long.

Comment: how will you find if a function is running unless it has return a value?

Comment: Need to be clearer: `If a function is true` VS `if functionOne has already run`, what do you mean. You want to `if(functionOne() == true) { functionThree(); }` or `if(functionOne has runnned before) { functionThree(); }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the working solution to be....

```
var clicked = false;

function functionOne() {
 /functionOne parameters
 clicked = true;
 }

function functionTwo() {
clicked = false;
//functionTwo parameters
}

functionFour() {
if (clicked) {
cliked = false;
functionFive()
} else {
//functionFour parameters
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a new boolean variable that is false when it's defined, but set to true when functionOne is run and that determines which function buttonTwo runs.

```
<html>
<script>
    var oneClicked = false;

    function functionOne() {
        oneClicked = true;
        alert('functionOne');
    }

    function functionTwo() {
        alert('functionTwo');
    }

    function functionThree() {
        alert('functionThree');
    }
</script>

<button onclick="functionOne()">button one</button>
<button onclick="if (oneClicked) {functionThree()} else {functionTwo()}">button two</button>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right idea, but your example would be much better if you [did not use inline attribute event handlers in html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572)